# Understanding psr-4 autoload function with composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

[image]I am trying to understand the autoloading part with composer. Attached image is my project structure.

**index.php**

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

// require "app/Controller/MyController.php"; // If i uncomment this my code is working fine. (only for testing purpose)

$mynamespace = new App\Controller\MyController();

$mynamespace->index();
```

**composer.json**

```
"psr-4": {
         "App\\": "app/" 
         }
```

**MyController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

class MyController{


    public function index(){
        echo "New  World";
    }
}
```

I ran composer dump-autoload and the file is not loaded.

How to map the autoloaded file via composer? I might go with multiple folders and files. So i prefer it to be one single directory as app/

[image]

Comment: What does your `MyController.php` file look like?

Comment: in addition have you run `composer install` ?

Comment: no change.. still i am getting class not found

Comment: How about your composer, can you updated it? Can you post the entire composer.json also?

Comment: I got it. I missed autoload in composer.json. Thanks for pointing to recheck the composer.json

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    "name": "alaksandarjesus/testnamespace",
    "authors": [{
        "name": "alaksandarjesus",
        "email": "abc@yahoo.co.in"
    }],
    "require": {},
    "autoload": { // Missed this autoload and so it didnt load.
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app"
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, so not sure if helpful:

```
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use App\Controller\MyController;

$mynamespace = new MyController();

$mynamespace->index();
```

or possibly escape the top level namespace:

```
$mynamespace = new \App\Controller\MyController();
```